# Как написать на JS Для определенной страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно написать javascript лишь для header`a странички "Home", а для остальных страниц — нужно сделать так, чтобы он не работал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Вот код, который нужен только для странички "Home".

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('header').toggleClass('header__shadow', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
      });
    
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var height = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(height < 200){
        $('header').addClass('header__bg');
        } else{
        $('header').removeClass('header__bg');
        }

});
```

Comment: а что мешает вписать скрипт в тег `<script>твой код</script>`

Comment: Ещё можно взять какой-то React, Vue, Angular и у вас javascript будет разделён. К примеру у вас будет компонент header, в котором будет прописана своя логика и вам там не надо ручками отделять

Comment: @AndreyFreiz , вот этот код не работает в теге script. Я только начинающий в JS, можете подсказать, как быть? Сам код: 
  `$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(height < 200){
    $('header').addClass('header__bg');
    } else{
    $('header').removeClass('header__bg');
    }
    });`

Comment: @МихаилКамахин я только начинаю, поэтому еще не работаю с React, Vue и Angular`ом.

Comment: @Dikkkey перенеси код в вопрос для читаемости

Comment: @AndreyFreiz готово

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто на странице Home добавь

```
    <script>
       $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('header').toggleClass('header__shadow', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
      });
    
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var height = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(height < 200){
        $('header').addClass('header__bg');
        } else{
        $('header').removeClass('header__bg');
        }

});
</script>
```

Comment: И не забудь подключить jquery перед <script>

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Писал так, но не работало из-за того, что перед скриптом не подключил jquery)

Comment: Рад был помочь! Удачи! )

Answer (score 2):

`if(window.location.pathname === '/Home'){`
....
`}`

если нужно делать сложную проверку используйте регулярку

`if(/Home\/.*/.test(window.location.pathname)){`
....
`}`

Comment: А подскажите, пожалуйста, как в этот код интегрировать эту проверку? Что-то я кручу, не совсем понимаю. 
`$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('header').toggleClass('header__shadow', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(height < 200){
    $('header').addClass('header__bg');
    } else{
    $('header').removeClass('header__bg');
    }
});`

Comment: Перенес код в вопрос

Comment: https://codepen.io/Manfrid/pen/BazpVRd?editors=1010   ну если у вас именно путь /Home